# Django API timezone Dates in UTC

Tags: django, date, datetime, timezone

I'm developing an API in Django (note not DRF).

I'm having this problem with datetime timezones.
I'm storing everything in UTC, then in front-end I convert them to current timezone with `moment.js`.

But then I have the problem with `DateFields`, for example:

```
confirm_pickup_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Where the `confirm_pickup_date` can either be server current time, or custom date sent by the client from front-end as `YYYY-MM-DD` format.
When i send the date by the client, i cant convert the Date to UTC

Comment: what is the problem. `I'm storing everything in UTC, then in front-end I convert them to current timezone with moment.js.` This is the solution to your problem

Comment: This is the prlblem
`But then I have the problem with DateFields, for example:

confirm_pickup_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
Where the confirm_pickup_date can either be server current time, or custom date sent by the client from front-end as YYYY-MM-DD format.`

Comment: `i cant convert the Date to UTC` What did you try to convert the date? Is there any error you saw?

Comment: When the user sends a custom date, than i need to convert that date to UTC format. 
For example, user sends '2017-09-12' from Chicago US, to be converted to UTC.

Comment: why not convert it to UTC on the frontend using moment.js

Comment: So what i was planing to do is, send `YYYY-MM-DD` from frontend, append `"hh:mm"` to the date, and convert the whole `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm` to UTC